# How to make an image as a button and redirect it to another page?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgbtn_RoleGuideWin8" runat="server"  ImageUrl="~/Images/Windows Logo.png" Width="215px" OnClick="imgbtn_RoleGuideWeb_Click" OnClientClick="fnOnWin8ButtonClick()" />
```

I have this code using asp.net.I want to convert it to HTML. For doing that I have written this code:

```
<input type="image" src="/Images/Windows Logo.png" id="myButton" />
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById("myButton").onclick = function () {
location.href = "www.google.com";
};
</script>
```

But this is not working. Any poninters?

Comment: You'd be better off wrapping an `img` tag with an `a` tag;  it'll be a lot easier in the long run.

Comment: basically what I want to achieve is use a image as button and when I click on that image it should redirect me to a page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
#myButton{
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  }

#myButton img{
    display:block;
    width: 200px;
  }

#myButton:hover{
  background: wheat;
  }
```

```html
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:location.href='http://www.google.com';" id="myButton">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png" alt="you should use alt tags" />
    </a>
```

Note that I moved your ID to the `<a>` tag so you can style that as you wish to make it look like a button

Comment: Thanks. It helped me but..I want use javascript code in it bcoz I want to add more functionality to it.I want to redirect it using that only.
How Can I do that with <a> tag?

Comment: Copy it somewhere else, outside of stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

```html
<form name="test" method="post" action="http://www.example.com">
  <input id="tst" type="submit"/>
  </form>
```

Then in css file, you should use this code:

```css
#tst
{
background-image:url("https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png");//or other urls.
}
```